# GridSearchCV.best_score_ meaning when scoring set to 'accuracy' and CV

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm trying to find the best model Neural Network model applied for the classification of breast cancer samples on the well-known Wisconsin Cancer dataset (569 samples, 31 features + target). I'm using sklearn 0.18.1. I'm not using Normalization so far. I'll add it when I solve this question.

```
# some init code omitted
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Define params NN params for the GridSearchCV

```
tuned_params = [{'solver': ['sgd'], 'learning_rate': ['constant'], "learning_rate_init" : [0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1]},
                {"learning_rate_init" : [0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1]}]
```

CV method and model

```
cv_method = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True)
model = MLPClassifier()
```

Apply grid

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=tuned_params, cv=cv_method, scoring='accuracy')
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = grid.predict(X_test)
```

And if I run:

```
print(grid.best_score_)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

The result is *0.746478873239* and *0.902097902098*

According to the doc "best_score_ : float, Score of best_estimator on the left out data". I assume it is the best accuracy among the ones obtained running the 8 different configuration as especified in *tuned_params* the number of times especified by KFold, on the left out data as especified by KFold. Am I right?

One more question. Is there a method to find the optimal size of test data to use in *train_test_split* which defaults to 0.25?

Thanks a lot

REFERENCES

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-nested-cross-validation-iris-py

Comment: Its the average of all cv folds for a single combination of given parameters. Check out the `cv_results_`. It will give you more details.

Comment: And about the second question, it depends on various factors like data, algorithm, etc and maybe more suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar, *cv_results_* has everything I needed. Thanks a lot. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: I can post the comment as an answer and then you can accept it.

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar, yes please do. I'll post the contents of *cv_results_* for others to have an example of the output.

Comment: Yes, sure. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `grid.best_score_` is the average of all cv folds for a single combination of the parameters you specify in the `tuned_params`.

In order to access other relevant details about the grid searching process, you can look at the `grid.cv_results_` attribute.

From the [documentation of GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV):

> cv_results_ : dict of numpy (masked) ndarrays
>
> ```
> A dict with keys as column headers and values as columns, 
> that can be imported into a pandas DataFrame
> ```

It contains keys like 'split0_test_score',
'split1_test_score' ,
'mean_test_score',
'std_test_score',
'rank_test_score',
'split0_train_score',
'split1_train_score',
'mean_train_score',
etc, which gives additional information about the whole execution.

Comment: To be more specific, the average of the test cv folds right?